salvar datos de mapa en un pdf usando jsPDF
les comento hay un problema en este mapa pongo link a continuación: https://wiseombudsman.org/map resulta que este mapa esta creado con un plugin llamado mapsvg en wordpress si seleccionas una locacion en la barra derecha y haces click en "Download Pdf" se supone que tiene que guardar un pdf o si llenas el formulario en la barra de lado izquierdo tambien se guarda, pero cuando haces ambas acciones el boton no hace absolutamente nada
aqui esta el script implementado en el boton


<a href="javascript:saveDiv()">
  <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> Download PDF</a>

<script>
     function saveDiv(){
 if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
{
  var directory = document.getElementById('left-sidebar').innerHTML;
}else{
 var directory =  document.getElementById('right-sidebar').innerHTML;
}
    var template = "<html><head></head><body> <style> img{width:50px; height:35px; text-align:center; margin:30px;} h5{font-size:20px; font-weight:700; color: #544d9d; margin:0;} h2{margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:20px;} span{margin-top:100px; color:#a60000; line-height:20px;}</style><span> Disclaimer: WISE & Healthy Aging does not make facility recommendations. This list was generated based on <br/>the selected criteria and should not be considered an endorsement of any facility.</span>" + "<img decoding='async' src='https://wiseombudsman.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/logo_ombudsman.png' alt='The Image' />" + "<h2> FACILITY LOCATOR LIST </h2>" + directory + "</body></html>";
             var doc = new jsPDF();
       doc.fromHTML(
         template, 10, 12,
           {
           width: 500,
       },
         
        
     function(a) {   
         window.open(doc.output("bloburl"), "_blank");
      });  
     }
  setInterval(function(){ 
    jQuery('#right-sidebar .mapsvg-pagination-container').empty();
    jQuery('#left-sidebar .mapsvg-pagination-container').empty();
    }, 1000);
</script>




¿cuál es la pregunta?
